# Problema na atualização do Composer - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Boa tarde a todos

Estou tentando instalar um pacote pelo composer no laravel, e ao digitar "composer require bert/ldap-authenticator" ele faz a instalação, mas produz o seguinte resultado:

```
Using version ^0.2.4 for berg/ldap-authenticator
./composer.json has been updated
> php artisan clear-compiled
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies <including require-dev)
- Removing doctrine/dbal (v2.5.1)
- Removing phpspec/php-diff (v1.0.2)
- Removing doctrine/common (v2.5.0)
- Removing doctrine/annotations (v1.2.6)
- Removing doctrine/cache (v1.4.1)
- Removing doctrine/collections (v1.3.0)
- Removing doctrine/lexer (v1.0.1)
- Removing spekkionu/laravel-zend-acl (2.0.2)
- Removing zendframework/zend-permissions-acl (2.3.9)
- Removing rmccue/requests (v1.6.1)
- Removing guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.0.2)
- Removing illuminate/html (v5.0.0)
- Removing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.1.0)
- Removing psr/http-message (1.0)
- Removing guzzlehttp/promises (1.0.1)
- Removing danielstjules/stringy (1.10.0)
- Removing phpspec/phpspec (2.2.1)
- Removing xethron/migrations-generator (dev-15 e5e86ef)
- Removing way/generators (dev-feature/laravel-five-stable)

[RuntimeException]

Failed to execute git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no
'git' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-plugins] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-regs] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Daí entro no sistema e tudo parou de funcionar. A minha sorte que quando fui fazer o update eu tinha feito um backup logo antes.

O que será que está acontecendo? Não acredito que seja algum conflito com o pacote que estou instalando.

Comment: Quando foi instalar o pacote o composer atualizou automaticamente o composer.json e o composer.lock (chutando). Algum pacote foi atualizado nisso, na segunda linha ele informa `./composer.json has been updated` tenta subir do backup somente o composer.lock para ver se foi isso

Comment: Foi não. Subi só o composer.lock, mas mesmo assim ele não tinha sido algerado

Comment: É estranho, mas o composer nunca removeu essas coisas nas instalações anteriores!

Answer (score -1):

Você provavelmente não está com o GIT instalado, ou o git não está no PATH do seu sistema. De qualquer forma eu recomendo você excluir a pasta VENDOR e executar novamente no composer install